# Create if-elif statements using for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I am dealing with an issue that involves multiple if and elif conditining..precisely stating, my case goes as follows:

```
if len(g) == 2:
   a = 'rea: 300'
   b = 'ref: "%s": {"sds": 200},"%s": {"sds": 300}' % (g[0],g[1])

elif len(g) == 3:
   a = 'rea: 400'
   b = 'ref: "%s": {"sds": 200},"%s": {"sds": 300},"%s": {"sds": 400}' % (g[0],g[1],g[2])
....
```

And this elif conditioning is supposed to go up to elif len(g) == 99...so I suppose there should be some elegant way to do this. Moreover, if you observe, there is a pattern with which the 'rea' and 'ref' are progressing, which can be stated as:

```
 if len(g) == x:
    a = 'rea: (x*100)+100'
    b = 'ref: "%s": {"sds": 200},"%s": {"sds": 300},"%s": {"sds": (x*100)+100}' % (g[0],g[1],g[2])
```

Comment: is b supposed to be a dictionary? Why recreate it as as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
g_len = len(g)
a = "rea: {}".format((g_len + 1) * 100)
b = "ref: "
for i, g_i in enumerate(g):
    b += ' "{}": {{"sds": {}}},'.format(g_i, (i+2) * 100)
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant one..thanks Mishik and Burhan! :-)

Comment: one more thing guys..how to implement this on Python 2.6 or 2.4? There maybe a little syntax change i believe..

Comment: I don't really remember much of 2.6 issues. What's not working?

Comment: IT is raising this exception: b += ' "{}": {{"sds": {}}},'.format(g_i, (i+2) * 100) ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Hm... I guess it does not like `{}`. Try using `"{0}": {{"sds": {1}}},`

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
def func(g):
    if not 1 < len(g) < 100:
        raise ValueError('inadequate length')
    d = {x:{'sds':(i+2)*100} for i, x in enumerate(g)}
    a = 'rea: %s00' % (len(g)+1)
    b = 'ref: %s' % str(d)[1:-1]
    return (a, b)
```

I don't know why you are creating a string `b` which looks very much like a dictionary, but I am sure you have your reasons...

```
>>> func(range(3))
('rea: 400', "ref: 0: {'sds': 200}, 1: {'sds': 300}, 2: {'sds': 400}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
x = 100
d = {}
for i in xrange(2, len(g)+1):
    d[i] = ['rea: {}'.format(100+x*i), 'ref: '+ ('%s: {"sds": 200}, ' *(i-1) + ' %s: {"sds": 200}') % tuple(g[:i])]
```

Now, d will look something like:

```
{2: ['rea: 300',
     'ref: "depends_on_g": {"sds": 200}, "depends_on_g": {"sds": 300}'],
 3: ['rea: 400',
     'ref: "depends_on_g": {"sds": 200}, "depends_on_g": {"sds": 300}', "depends_on_g": {"sds": 300}]
 ...
}
```

Then, to access it:

```
a, b = d.get(len(g))
```

No if-statements needed :)

Comment: "ref" value should be increasing for each i

Comment: @mishik I just notcied that :)

Comment: And you now have a dict of n^2 size, storing all the non required values :)

Comment: @mishik What :p? Firstly, my dict is length 98, and secondly, it gets the contents from `g` fine.

Comment: The dict is 98 length alright, but d[1] is X long, d[1] is 2X long, etc... d[99] ix 99X long :)
`X + 2X + ... + 99X = 4950X`

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would go for something functional at the time that the length was known like:

```
def do_Condition(g):
    """ Condtion the result based on the length of g """
    l = len(g)
    a = 'rea: %d' % (100 + 100*l)
    items = ['ref: "%s"' % (g[0])]
    n = 100
    for i in g[1:]:
        n += 100
        items.append('{"sds": %d},"%s"' % (n, i))
    b = ': '.join(items)
    return (a, b)
```

Comment: You don't need to store the `len(g)` as a variable, the length is always calculated and calling the length method on a container does not re-evaluate each time, it only retrieves the value, it is actually *slower* to store length as a separate value.

Answer (score -1):

this seems to work:

```
a = 'rea: %d00' % (len(g)+1)
b = ",".join(['ref: "%s": {"sds": %d00}' % (i, j) for i, j in  zip(g, range(2,len(g)+2))])
```